# Find $m,n$ such that $1+m\cos(x+a)+n\cos2(x+b)+\cos3x \ge 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Find all $m,n$ such that

$$1+m\cos(x+a)+n\cos2(x+b)+\cos3x \ge0 \textrm{ for all } x\in \mathbb{R}$$

Please give me some hints. I don't have any idea.
Thanks.

Comment: No. a,b just are real numbers. I'm stuck with this

Comment: It looks weird you have $\,+1\,$ in both sides of the inequality...

Comment: Sorry. I just fix it

Answer (score 2):

Assume $a,b$ are given. Demand that:

$$\min(1+m\cos(x+a)+n\cos2(a+b)+\cos3x)=1-m+n\cos(2a+2b)-1\ge0$$
$$n\cos(2a+2b)\ge m$$
So that for any pair $m,n$ such that:
$$\frac{n}{m}\ge\cos(2a+2b)$$
Your equation will be larger or equal to $0$ for all $x$.

Comment: How we get m=n=0. What special value of x which we choose? $\pi/3$?

Comment: @tangkhaihanh - you don't need to choose a value for $x$. Also, if you like an answer, please upvote and / or accept it - You've asked 24 question but only given 5 upvotes on the entire site..

Comment: We have to find m,n. How can we choose m=n=0?

Comment: @nububis I'm sorry. And thank you. I have upvote useful anwers which I like and

Comment: @tangkhaihanh - you asked to find $m,n$ such that. $m=n=0$ are such an example.

Comment: Sorry. I meant "find all"

Comment: @tangkhaihanh - fixed